# How can i retrieve the "values" of json with R?

Tags: json, r, key-value

So i tried anything to get a specific key:value. But it seems that i cant find a solution for this. Any help?

```html
{  
   "contracts":[  
      {  
         "contractid":"BemDRHtv17",
         "cid":"",
         "category":"WORK",
         "mainCategory":"Grundeinkommen",
         "configured":false,
         "customMainCategory":null,
         "customSubCategory":null,
         "customContractPartner":null,
         "amount":209200,
         "interval":"MONTHLY",
         "runTime":null,
         "periodOfNotice":null,
         "cancelationAlert":null,
         "extensionPeriod":null,
         "contractPartner":{  
            "creditorId":null,
            "name":null,
            "__typename":"ContractPartner"
         },
         "__typename":"Contract"
      },
```

P.s i'm trying to access the key and value of mainCategory / search for its specific values.

Comment: Have you tried [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) or [`rjson`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html)? Please show any code you've tried so far.

Comment: nvm fixed it. 
i just created a small data frame with the information needed. 
Like this : 
me <- data_frame(
  contract = c(vertrag$contracts[3]),
  mainCategory = c(vertrag$contracts[4]),
  amount = c(vertrag$contracts[9])
)

Answer (score 3):

You can access certain key using the following approach

using libraries like `rjson` , `jsonlite`

calling the json data into R using `fromJSON()` function. Lets say you saved the data like this

```
library(jsonlite)
jsonData = fromJSON("PATH")  #Link to the file or html link
```

Now you can parse what you what using this approach and save the result in a matrix (or whatever data class you want to use)

```
variable <- as.matrix(jsonData$contracts$mainCategory)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I realized how easy it is to access json elements just by using the $ char...

Answer (score 3):

Rather than converting your whole JSON to an R object, you can use [`library(jqr)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jqr/vignettes/jqr_vignette.html) to access specific elements of raw JSON

```
library(jqr)

jq(js, ".contracts[].mainCategory")

# "Grundeinkommen"
```

---

#### Data

```
js <- '{  
   "contracts":[  
{  
"contractid":"BemDRHtv17",
"cid":"",
"category":"WORK",
"mainCategory":"Grundeinkommen",
"configured":false,
"customMainCategory":null,
"customSubCategory":null,
"customContractPartner":null,
"amount":209200,
"interval":"MONTHLY",
"runTime":null,
"periodOfNotice":null,
"cancelationAlert":null,
"extensionPeriod":null,
"contractPartner":{  
"creditorId":null,
"name":null,
"__typename":"ContractPartner"
},
"__typename":"Contract"
}
]}
'
```